# Why does a Kohain (or Kohain's wife) take challah?

Tags: kohen-priest, separating-challah

It is a mitzvah to take challah from dough before baking when making the requisite amount of bread. All Jews are obligated in this mitzvah. When the Temples were still standing (may this be the situation again soon!) this dough was given to a Kohain. In our times, sadly, it is burned. Why are Kohenim (and their wives) currently obligated in this mitzvah?

Comment: Why should they not be obligated? At the very least, taking challah makes the rest of the dough permitted to non-kohanim, so it's not like it has no effect.

Comment: Do you mean currently as opposed to back then? Why is now different? Are you asking about challa as opposed to all the other tithes? Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119265/759